# Store color information in MySQL and parse Red, Green and Blue values in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql, colors, hex

I am developing a web application which uses a lot of Color Data in MySQL. The usual processes that I am using include an average color calculation based on some visual data and later perform search queries on these colors.

[image]

What I did so far was storing the average calculated color into a Hex (simple varchar (6)) column and also stored the R G B values into INT columns. Later on I was able to perform these kind of queries to search through colors.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE ( ABS(color1_red - $red) + ABS(color1_blue-$blue) + ABS(color1_green - $green) < $color_threshold) order by id desc";
```

The database structure for that looked like this.

But as I am performing a database update I noticed there was a lot of repetition going on with my data so I was wondering if there was a better way to store color in MySQL.

I was thinking trying to do something like that:
[image]

using the table Color

[image]

The problem that arises from making a table color is that here is a fixed number of colors in hex format so is there really a reason for a table once you can access that color information from PHP?
But the problem that arises from the old structure is that there is a bit of repetition and the tables look clumsy.

Is there a good way to store color information in MySQL and/or is there a way to write this function

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE (ABS (color1_red - $red) + ABS (color1_blue-$blue) + ABS (color1_green - $green) < $color_threshold) order by id desc";
```

Using only a HEX column and avoid the red, green, blue (int()) columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BIGINT type for this. And field will be from 0 (#000000) to 16777215 (#FFFFFF).
And it's easy to get HEX value using HEX() function in MySQL and to calcalate int values for red green and blue too. For example if we store color this way and it is 16000003 then:

For red:
SELECT (
( 16000003 )
DIV ( 256 *256 )
)

For green:
SELECT (
( 16000003 % ( 256 *256 ) )
DIV 256
)

For blue:
SELECT (
( 16000003 % ( 256 *256 ) ) %256
)

Comment: Looks good but isnt the BIGINT data type consuming a lot of storage space? Also would this calulation on the spot be efficient enough or is it better to store the RGB values in the database in the first place?

Comment: BIGINT consumes 8 bytes only. Less than VARCHAR(6) or three int fields total. And this calculations are very fast and you don't have to worry about this. Also it's possible to store all nine digits of RGB in one field (from 0 to 255255255) and it's easy to extract red green and blue too and it's better in terms of visualization.

Comment: Thanks I am going to try both solutions see what fits best